# TensorFlow: discarding convolution gradients/parameters at test time

Tags: tensorflow, memory, conv-neural-network

Lately I've been reading up on the memory consumed by convolutional neural networks (ConvNets). During training, each convolutional layer has several parameters required for back-propagation of the gradients. [These lecture notes](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#comp) suggest that these parameters can in principle be discarded at test time. A quote from the linked notes:

> Usually, most of the activations are on the earlier layers of a ConvNet (i.e. first Conv Layers). These are kept around because they are needed for backpropagation, but a clever implementation that runs a ConvNet only at test time could in principle reduce this by a huge amount, by only storing the current activations at any layer and discarding the previous activations on layers below.

Is there any way (using TensorFlow) to make use of this "clever implementation" for inference of large batches? Is there some flag that specifies whether or not the model is in its training phase? Or is this already handled automatically based on whether the optimiser function is called?

Comment: Could you be more specific? You mean using a trained model for inference? Or just switching between train/test? Or quantization?

Comment: Being able to switch between training and validation/testing mode on the fly would be ideal, but using a trimmed-down trained model for inference would already be helpful. Instead of performing inference on a few images at a time (limited by the available memory), reducing the footprint of the trained model would allow me to do inference on larger batches. I'm not talking about quantisation here.

Comment: Your question is still too broad. Graph can be frozen and processed with `optimize_for_inference_lib`. This will discard some operations only needed for training. I'm not sure if TF has smth 'on the fly'

Comment: @Sharky `optimize_for_inference_lib` is a useful pointer. From what I gathered, this operation discards training-specific components of the model, which would already be helpful in making inference more efficient.

Comment: Then you can share what you've managed to find out and answer your own question